# Qt Quick: How to get the current text from ComboBox

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I try to get text from the current index from ComboBox. `model.get(scale).text` method doesn't work, it only gets the first index.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
Column{
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    id:optionsColumn
    spacing: 5
    anchors.fill : parent
    anchors.topMargin    : 15
    anchors.bottomMargin : 15
    anchors.leftMargin :15
    anchors.rightMargin  : 15
    ComboBox {
        id: scale
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        editable: true
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
        currentIndex: 1
        model: ListModel {
            id: model
            ListElement { text: "500" }
            ListElement { text: "1000" }
            ListElement { text: "2000" }
            ListElement { text: "5000" }
            ListElement { text: "10000" }
            ListElement { text: "25000" }
        }
        onAccepted: {
            id:maccepted
            if (find(editText) === -1)
                model.append({text: editText})
        }
    }
    Button{
        id:showtext
        text: "Scale to text"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onClicked: {
            var a=parseFloat(model.get(scale).text)
            scaletext.text=a
        }
    }
    TextField{
        id:scaletext
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        readOnly: true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should get your example right. `ComboBox.accepted` has been introduced in `QtQuick.Controls 2.2`, and is not available in the imported `2.0`

Comment: What exactly do you expect with `model.get(scale).text`? `model.get()` expects an `int` index, you pass a `Q(t)Object`.

Comment: I expected it to get the current text from combobox. I referenced it from Qt docs. Now scale.currentText works as expected.

Comment: You seem to have strange docs. I can't find a `get`-method that takes `QtObjects`. I can only find [**this one.**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method)

Comment: [This](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qml-qtquick-controls-combobox.html) one is from ComboBox doc. And I referenced from ' onCurrentIndexChanged: console.debug(cbItems.get(currentIndex).text + ", " + cbItems.get(currentIndex).color)'

Comment: That one is about another library, `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` - you need to be wary with the major version of the `QtQuick.Controls` as version `1.x` and `2.x` are completly different. Further, they are passing the value of the property [`currentIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qml-qtquick-controls-combobox.html#currentIndex-prop) to the method, which is an `int`. This would work with your code as well. You would need to call `model.get(scale.currentIndex)` instead. I hope I could clear some of your misconceptions.

Comment: I didn't know about this. Thanks. Now I understand some examples didn't work because of this. I am new to QML and I will research about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have fun.

```
onClicked: {
  //var a=parseFloat(model.get(scale).text)
  scaletext.text = scale.currentText; 
}
```